# How to connect an iOS Swift app to a .Net app on Windows 10 by a socket

Tags: .net, swift, sockets, websocket

I need to send data from our mobile app on iOS to our backend .Net app on Windows 10.

I want to get this going quickly, so I'd prefer the simplest socket approach.

This will be for high speed, continuous full-duplex data communication;
some control data will flow asynchronously in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use starscream for iOS as a websocket client